# Date handling in bash, unexplainable behavior

Tags: bash, date

I'm having some maddening issues with handling dates in a bash script. After stripping everything else from the script, I can reproduce the behavior using the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

date1=`date -u -d "2015-11-04 11:54"`
date2=`date -u -d "2015-11-04 11:55"`

start=`date -u -d "2015-11-04 9:25:00"`
end=`if [[ "$date1" < "$date2" ]];then echo $date1;else echo $date2;fi`

now=$start
echo "now   = "$now
echo "end   = "$end
echo "date1 = "$date1

until [ "$now" == "$date1" ]
do
    echo $now
    now=$(date -u -d "$now 1 minute")
done
echo "first loop done"

now=$start
until [ "$now" == "$end" ]
do
    echo $now
    now=$(date -u -d "$now 1 minute")
done
echo "second loop done"

exit 0
```

The first block of `echo` lines will show that `end` and `date1` are identical, as they should be because of the `if` statement before. The first `until` loop does exactly what you expect: loop by minute until `now`is one minute before `date1`. The second loop, however, keeps going forever. How can this be when `end`and `date1` are identical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the quotes on your echo lines to *after* the variables (i.e. `echo "end   = $end"` and `echo "date1 = $date1"`) and you'll see the difference you were missing before.

You see (and think you have in your variables):

```
now   = Wed Nov 4 09:25:00 UTC 2015
end   = Wed Nov 4 11:54:00 UTC 2015
date1 = Wed Nov 4 11:54:00 UTC 2015
```

Fix your variable quoting on the `echo`s however and you get:

```
now   = Wed Nov  4 09:25:00 UTC 2015
end   = Wed Nov 4 11:54:00 UTC 2015
date1 = Wed Nov  4 11:54:00 UTC 2015
```

And there's the difference.

To fix the problem you need to quote the values in the sub-shell `if` block `echo` commands too.

Alternatively don't use a sub-shell and `echo` at all:

```
if [[ "$date1" < "$date2" ]]; then
    end=$date1
else
    end=$date2
fi
```

As a general rule **always** quote your variable expansions and *never* use `echo` like that to check variable values. At very least quote when you do. But both `printf '%q\n' "$variable"` and `declare -p variable` (for bash) are much better for that job.

Comment: Yep, you're right. Although the actual fix I needed for the complete, more complicated script, was to use the output of the `if` to create a new date (end=\`date -u -d "$(if...fi)'`).